# How can I linearize the distance from two points?

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming, linearization

I'm studying Operations Resarch and the professor give us the following problem:

• There is a 10*10 matrix in which there are 20 villages on random coordinates.

• We have to drop two supply packages (let's say a and b).

• Once a packages are dropped, each village is assigned to the closest package.

The objective is to find Xa,Ya and Xb,Yb in order to minimize the sum of these distances.

The problem is that the model has to be linear (Linear Programming) and with less than 300 variables.
I think I found a model but I've used the non-linear distance function.

There's a way to linearize it?

Thanks.

Edit: my current model is:

$ X_1 $= row of the first package
$ Y_1 $= column of the first package


$ X_2 $= row of the second package 
$ Y_2 $= column of the secondo package 


$ X_vi $= row of the i-village 
$ Y_vi $= column of the i-village 
forall i from 1 to 20.

define $d_xi$ as the distance of the i-village from the x-package
$$
d_1i = sqrt[2]((X_1 - X_vi)^2 + (Y_1 - Y_vi)^2)
$$
$$
d_2i = sqrt[2]((X_2 - X_vi)^2 + (Y_2 - Y_vi)^2)
$$

logic variables:
$ L_1i $= 1 iif d_1i less than d_2i, 0 otherwise 
$ L_2i $= 1 iif d_2i less than d_1i, 0 otherwise

objective function:
minimize: $ \sum_{i=0}^{20} ((d_1i * L_1i) + (d_2i * L_2i)) $

constraints:
$ L_1i + L_2i = 1 \tag 1$
$ (d_2i - d_1i) * L_1i >= 0 \tag 2$ 
$ (d_1i - d_2i) * L_2i <= 0 \tag 3$ 
• all the coordinates are contained in {1,2,...,10} 

i think this is less-equal-than 300 variables

Comment: Show us your model so we can help you linearize it.

Comment: Can the packages be dropped anywhere? Or are they dropped in one of the 20 villages. If so it is a clustering problem, easy to model with linear constraints.

Comment: edited right now

Comment: Your constraints (2) and (3) are also not linear…but you can linearize them with disjunctive constraints:  $d_2i\le d_1i + M(1-L_2i)$, where M is a large integer.

Comment: for example M = 9999 is large enough?

Comment: Suppose $L_2i=0$, i.e. $d_2i>d_1i$. Constraint (2) becomes $d_2i\le d_1i+M$, so to be valid you can take for instance $M=\sqrt{20^2+20^2}=20\sqrt{2}$. This way the constraint will be true even if both packages are at opposite corners of your matrix.

Comment: ok thanks, your help is very precious to me... I'll modify the constraints (2) and (3) with that method.
Now my problem is only to linearize the distances $ d_2i $ and $ d_1i $

Comment: Yes I think your best option now is to use  @Michael Medvinsky's trick: Minimizing $\sqrt{(X_1-X_vi)^2+(Y_1-Y_vi)^2}L_1i$ should be like minimizing $(|X_1-X_vi|+|Y_1-Y_vi|)L_1i$, although I am not 100% sure! If it is true than it is easy to linearize: Minimize $(a+b)L_1i$ and add the constraints $\pm a\le X_1-X_vi$ and $\pm b \le Y_1-Y_vi$.

Comment: I'll try, if it gives to me the solution I got with Java brute force ;-) it will be correct =)

Comment: using @Michael Medvinsky's trick dos not ensures that distance 1 is less than distance 2... anyway, the two packages can be dropped anywhere in the matrix, there is a clustering variant to solve this?

Comment: What do you mean "using @Michael Medvinsky's trick dos not ensure that distance 1 is less than distance 2" ? Indeed, it is not meant to. Constraints  (2) and (3) take care of this.

To my knowledge, there is no clustering variant if the packages can be dropped anywhere. This is because such models rely on the fact that there is a finite number of locations possible, and therefore a finite number of boolean variables for each location possible. If the packages can be dropped anywhere, the clustering model would have an infinite number of variables. Perhaps there is some way around this issue?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Constraints (2) and (3) are ok. 
Let's say that $ d_1i = sqrt(a^2 + b^2) <= |a| + |b| $ and  $ d_2i = sqrt(c^2 + d^2) <= |c| + |d| $
We need $ L_1i $ and $ L_2i $ to be 0 or 1 comparing the distances $ d_1i  $ and $ d_2i $. But if we use the absolute values, then we cannot say for sure that distance 1 is less than distance 2 or viceversa.

Comment: Yes you can, it is done in constraints (2) and (3). The absolute values are only for the objective function.

Comment: Any update here?

Comment: Nope, we are stuck but our professors gave us another project and we are currently focusing on it... sorry =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mixed integer linear programming formulation with 220 variables and $1+20\binom{100}{2}$ linear constraints.  Let $V=\{1,\dots,20\}$ denote the set of villages.  Let parameter $d_{i,j}^v$ denote the distance from village $v$ to location $(i,j)$.  Let $$P=\{(i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2)\in\{1,\dots,100\}^4:i_1 < i_2 \lor ((i_1 = i_2) \land (j_1 < j_2))\}$$ be the set of pairs of distinct locations. Let binary decision variable $y_{i,j}$ indicate whether a package is dropped at $(i,j)$, as in @Kuifje's answer.  Let decision variable $z_v$ be the distance from village $v$ to the closest package.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_v z_v$ subject to:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i,j} y_{i,j} &= 2\\
z_v &\ge \min\left(d_{i_1,j_1}^v,d_{i_2,j_2}^v\right)(y_{i_1,j_1}+y_{i_2,j_2}-1)&&\text{for all $v\in V, (i_1,j_1,i_2,j_2)\in P$}\\
y_{i,j} &\in\{0,1\}&&\text{for all $i,j$}
\end{align}
The idea is that $y_{i_1,j_1} = y_{i_2,j_2} = 1$ forces $z_v \ge \min\left(d_{i_1,j_1}^v,d_{i_2,j_2}^v\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

I would say please give more details on your non linear function.

In general if you function can be expressed as a sum of something linear and something that is non-linear and this non-linear part isn't a dominant part that you can just omit\truncate this non linear part, as long as it remains a distance function. 
$$d(x,y)=L(x)+NL(x)\quad\text{become}\quad \tilde d(x,y)=L(x)$$

I would call $\tilde d$ an approximation of $d$. However, the distortion created by this linearization may change the final result, which hopefully remains in a range acceptable error, i.e.
$$\|d(x,y)-\tilde d(x,y)\|<\epsilon,$$ otherwise I guess you cannot use this trick.

Comment: The function hat I have to linearize is the distance between two points... it is

sqrt((Xa - Xvi)^2 + (Ya - Yvi)^2)

calling Xa the x-coordinate of the package 'a'
Xvi the x-coordinate of the i-village
Ya the y-coordinate of the package 'a'
Yvi the y-coordinate of the i-village

Comment: hint - linear approximation would be the simplest thing to try, also $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\le |a|+|b|$

Answer (score 0):

How about this?
Define the following boolean variables:

- $y_{ij}=1$ if and only if a package is dropped at location $(i,j), i,j=1,…,10;$
- $x_{ij}^v=1$ if and only if village $v$ is assigned to location $(i,j), i,j=1,…,10,$ $v=1,…,20$.

Objective function: Minimize $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}\sum_{j=1}^{10}\sum_{v=1}^{20}d_{ij}^vx_{ij}^v$$

where $d_{ij}^v$ is the distance (known with the matrix) between village $v$ and location $(i,j)$, and add the following constraints:

- drop exactly 2 packages: $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}\sum_{j=1}^{10}y_{ij}=2$$
- assign each village to one of the packages: $$\sum_{i=1}^{10}\sum_{j=1}^{10}x_{ij}^v=1\quad \forall v=1,…,20$$
- a village can only be assigned to a location where there is a package: $$x_{ij}^v\le y_{ij}\quad \forall v=1,…,20,\quad \forall i,j=1,…,10$$

The model is linear, but it has more than 300 variables (it has 2100!). Maybe I misunderstood the problem. Maybe there is a way to get rid of some variables.

Comment: Yes, it's very similar to the "more-than-300-variables" solution that we found... and it made us earn 1 bonus point to the exam.
But the "less-than-300-variables" solution could make us earn bonus 4 points... so I'm searching for that solution.
Anyway thanks for your reply =)

Comment: Out of curiosity, I would love to see the "less-than-300-variables" linear solution once you get it!